# How to setup PhantomJS in C# program?

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I've been  looking around and nothing explains it well. It mentions Ghost driver and PhantomJS uses Java, but also mentions C#. I tried using PhantomJS but says a assembly is missing or not found. Do i need to reference Ghost driver assembly? But isn't in jar files and java? I don't get it. I am simply trying to get a headless browser for a C# program. Im currently using Chrome webdriver.

Comment: I would recommend looking here for some insperation: http://www.andykelk.net/tech/headless-browser-testing-with-phantomjs-selenium-webdriver-c-nunit-and-mono

Comment: Thanks! that helped. I just added the driver and added the selenium and nunit references!